# upload image to project directory and store other data in database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m working in form to upload image in project folder and store the  other data into Database. when I try to submit this form data was submitted and image was not uploaded and one more the image was uploaded and not all of data was stored in database this is my code

#### model:

```
function update_news($data) {

    extract($data);
    $this->db->where('news_id', $news_id);
    $this->db->update($table_name, array('title_en' => $title_en, 'title_ar' => $title_ar,'news_date' => $news_date,'image' => $image,'is_visible' => $is_visible,'main_news' => $main_news));
    return true;
}
```

#### controller

```
public function update() {
    $filename = $this->input->post('image');
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $this->input->post('news_date'));
    $data = array(
        'table_name' => 'news', // pass the real table name
        'news_id' => $this->input->post('news_id'),
        'title_en' => $this->input->post('title_en'),
        'title_ar' => $this->input->post('title_ar'),
        'news_date' => $this->input->post('news_date'),
        'image' => $date->format("Y") . '/' . $this->input->post('image'),
        'is_visible' => $this->input->post('is_visible'),
        'main_news' => $this->input->post('main_news')
    );

    $this->m_news_crud->update_news($data);

    $folderName = 'assets/images/press-news/2015';
    $config['upload_path'] = "$folderName";
    if (!is_dir($folderName)) {
        mkdir($folderName, 0777, TRUE);
    }

    $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post('image');
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;        
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 100;
    $config['max_width'] = 1024;
    $config['max_height'] = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile','image')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['error'] = $error;
        $data['title_en'] = $this->input->post('title_en');
        $data['title_ar'] = $this->input->post('title_ar');
        $data['news_date'] = $this->input->post('news_date');
        $data['image'] = base_url('assets/images/press-news/' . $date->format("Y")) . '/' . $this->input->post('image');
        $data['is_visible'] = $this->input->post('is_visible');
        $data['main_news'] = $this->input->post('main_news');
        $data['news_id'] = $this->input->post('news_id');
        $this->load->view('admin/news/d_admin_header');
        $this->load->view('admin/news/vcrudedit_news', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/news/d_admin_footer');
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        redirect('c_news_crud/get_news_data', $data);

        echo $filename;
    }
}
```

#### view:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <?php echo form_open('C_news_crud/update', 'role="form"  style="margin-top: 50px;"'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title_en">Title Name English</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title_en" name="title_en" value="<?php echo $title_en ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title_ar">Title Name Arabic</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title_ar" name="title_ar" value="<?php echo $title_ar ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <label for="is_visible">is visible</label>
            <?php
            if ($is_visible == 1) {
                $check_visible = 'checked="checked"';
            } else {
                $check_visible = ' ';
            }
            ?>

            <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="is_visible" class="cbox" <?php echo $check_visible; ?> name="is_visible" value="<?php echo $is_visible; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="main_news">Main Arabic</label>
            <?php
            if ($main_news == 1) {
                $check_main = 'checked="checked"';
            } else {
                $check_main = ' ';
            }
            ?>

            <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="main_news" class="cbox" <?php echo $check_main; ?> name="main_news" value="<?php echo $main_news; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="news_date">News date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="news_date" name="news_date" value="<?php echo $news_date ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" value="<?php echo $image ?>">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="news_id" value="<?php echo $news_id ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href = '<?php echo site_url('C_news_crud/get_news_data') ?>'" class="btn btn-success">Back</button>
    </form>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to select the file name as: `$_FILES['image']['name']` and not as `$this->input->post('image');` POST method is used to get your form data. $FILES is used to get all your files from the form.

Comment: that's it, thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the path to the uploading folder is correct and it has write permission.
2. Make sure you are referring to the correct file input name:

   ```
   $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   ```
3. set your uploading directory as `./assets/images/press-news/2015/`
4. You need to display the error you get so that you know what is causing the error!

   ```
   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
   }
   ```

[Codigniter's Upload Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: ok , i have been displayed the error and it give "You did not select a file to upload" and I'm already select it